# Python. Можно ли запустить один поток много раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Недавно начал изучать потоки в Python , конкретнее модуль threading.

И мне нужно сделать так чтобы после окончания потока , (то есть когда ввожу nameThrd.is_alive() оно выводит False) я мог бы запустить этот поток снова.

Весь код я не скинул потому , что сама программа на 200 символов , да ещё и с pyqt5.

Я делаю это так (уверен , что это не правильно):

```
def checkEvent():
    global run
    run = True
    while run == True:   
        for x in range(0,5):
            if (x == 5):
                run = False
                real_thrd()
def real_thrd () :
    checkplay = threading.Thread(target=checkEvent)
    checkplay.start()
#событие:
   real_thrd()
   ###Код который нужно выполнить во время работы потока
#событие:
   run = False
```

Как это будет правильно реализовать?

Python 3.8.3

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Если хотите переиспользовать потоки, применяйте thread pool.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , я буду благодарен если вы распишете как пользоваться thread pool

Comment: А зачем перезапускать тот же поток?

Comment: @dIm0n , сможете показать как реализовать функционал данной программы без перезапуска потока?

Comment: зачем вобще там потоки, если всёравно нужно ждать выполнения предыдущего ?

Comment: @MakeCheats я не понимаю, что эта программа пытается сделать :) Стоит привести исходную задачу, возможно вы выбрали не тот путь решения. Если же вы хотите перезапускать тот же поток для экономии ресурсов, то ОС сама прекрасно их переиспользует, если видит необходимость

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) модуль предоставляет интерфейс совместимый с multiprocessing, но для потоков, а не процессов.

[Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) это группа процессов, соединенная очередбю заданий с основным кодом.

Для запуска функции в потоке несколько раз:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
pool = Pool()

pool.apply_async(checkEvent)
```

Но  скорее Вам нужен `imap()` или `map_async()` метод - сложно сказать без описания кода. Этот интерфейс очень удобен для выволнения не связанного с qt напрямую кода. Идеально для работы с сетью и файлами и прочим вводом-выводом. Для тяжолой обработки массивов данных лучше использовать пул процессов.

Для Qt также существуют родные [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) и соответсвенно к ним [QThreadPool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html)

На основной класс добавьте пул

```
self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
```

Функцию с полезной работтой надо обернуть в класс QRunnable

```
class Worker(QRunnable):
    '''
    Worker thread
    '''

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        '''
        Your code goes in this function
        '''
        print("Thread start") 
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Thread complete")
```

И можно запускать несколько раз

```
worker = Worker()
self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

Очень подробная статья с примерами https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

Answer (score 1):

Эту задачу можно решить не перезапуская поток. Например, перезапуск можно организовать через [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#event-objects) зациклив `run()`

```
class Runner(threading.Thread):

     def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
         self.start_event = threading.Event()
         super().__init__(*a, **kw)

     def run(self):
         while self.start_event.wait():
             self.start_event.clear()
             self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

     def restart(self):
         self.start_event.set()
 

 t = Runner(target=work)
 t.start() # не начинает работу, ждет рестарт
 t.restart() # запускает target
 t.restart()
```